# How to Post this (Payjunction) request using C# .Net

Tags: asp.net, http, c#-4.0, request, payjunction

This is what I've tried:

```
curl -X POST -u "pj-ql-01:pj-ql-01p" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-PJ-Application-Key: YOUR_LABS_APP_KEY" \
-d "action=CHARGE" \
-d "cardNumber=4444333322221111" \
-d "cardExpMonth=01" \
-d "cardExpYear=2020" \
-d "amountBase=3.00" \
"https://api.payjunctionlabs.com/transactions"
```

Comment: Code from: https://developer.payjunction.com/tutorials/keyed-creditdebit-cards/

Answer (score 0):

```
UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
    string usernamePassword = "pj-ql-01" + ":" + "pj-ql-01p";
    string url = "https://api.payjunctionlabs.com/transactions";

    KeyValuePair<string, string> Credential = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(enc.GetBytes(usernamePassword)));
    KeyValuePair<string, string> HdrAppKey = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("X-PJ-Application-Key", "your key");

    string postData= "action=CHARGE&cardNumber=4444333322221111&cardExpMonth=01&cardExpYear=2020&amountBase=3.00&cardCvv=999";
    byte[] postDataBytes = enc.GetBytes(postData);
    HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    myReq.Method = "POST";
    myReq.Headers[Credential.Key] = Credential.Value;
    myReq.Headers[HdrAppKey.Key] = HdrAppKey.Value;

    myReq.KeepAlive = true;
    myReq.Accept = "application/json";
    myReq.MediaType = "application/json";
    myReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
    myReq.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;
    Stream myReqStream = myReq.GetRequestStream();
    myReqStream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
    try
    {
        string b;
        using (var response = myReq.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                b = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        Response.Write(b);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
        Response.Write("</br>");
        Response.Write(ex.StackTrace);
        Response.Write("</br>");
        test();

    }
```